# Tabela Fipe Trocar ano 3200

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá... tenho um sistema que puxa as informações da tabela fipe, mas ele puxa o ano de 2018 ou 2019 como 3200

Como trocar?

Esse é o código que busca através de um select dinâmico

```
$conectando = "SELECT * FROM fp_ano WHERE codigo_modelo = '$ano' ORDER BY 
 ano DESC";
$dados = mysql_query($conectando) or die(mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($dados) == 0){
  echo '<option value="0">'.htmlentities('Carregando...').'</option>';
  }else{
  echo '<option value="0">Escolha o ano desejado </option>';
  while($funcao002 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados)){
  echo utf8_encode('<option 
  value="'.$funcao002['id_ano'].'">'.$funcao002['ano'].'</option>');
  }
  }
```

[image: Foto]

[image: Banco de dados]

Comment: Cara, apresenta algum código aí. Eu tenho aqui um scraper da FIPE mas se você não apresentar nada pra mostrar pra gente fica complicado.

Comment: 3200 é o zero km

Comment: Editei o código... veja se consegue entender

Comment: Linha 73: https://github.com/Sorackb/VehicleReader/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lucassouza/vehiclereader/model/businessrule/YearPriceBR.java

Comment: Não entendo pq tbm está aparecendo 2 3200 (0KM

Comment: É pq tem o modelo 2018 e 2019 zero KM

Comment: E como faço aparecer 0Km ao inves de 3200 e como vou saber se é 2018 e 2019

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77710/discussion-between-betinho-silva-and-sorack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso mudando o código `3200` para `Zero KM` na camada de apresentação:

```
SELECT id_ano,
       CASE ano
         WHEN 3200 THEN 'Zero KM'
         ELSE ano
       END AS ano
  FROM fp_ano
 WHERE codigo_modelo = '$ano'
 ORDER BY ano DESC
```